# Is there a Java Android code to output a short pulse out the datawire of the USB port?

Tags: java, android, usb

I was wondering if it was possible to write a Java Android coder output a short 5V pulse out the datawire of the USB port, on the Android device

Answer (score 1):

USB is not designed for such a use, so your choices are either to misapply it, or to use it to ask something external to do what you want.

From the bare USB port, you could only do this by briefly enabling the USB VBus charge pump on a device with that capability, which would be a root-access (or quite possibly, kernel-driver) level task - and that would not of course be on the data line, but instead on the VBus line.

With an external microcontroller and circuitry connected, you could accomplish your end goal using either the ADK interface or USB host mode if supported, by having an app communicate a request to the micro to do it.

Comment: I wanted the app to interact with a ex. Microcontroller.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely no, the developers would never implement something like that. It's only possible by modificating the Android software, you would find it here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/usb/package-summary.html otherwise (I searched a bit but didn't find a method like that, you can only send data and stuff but you can't control the voltage and stuff like that).